# Close the last application on Pyside

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside, 3dsmax

I'm new guy with Pyside, i'm trying to create the plugin for 3DsMax 2015. Now i have a trouble with Cancel Button

I have a "Main Form"

[image]

When i click the "Add new objects", i will show the new form. We can call it is "Sub Form"

[image]

When i click button "Cancel" , All application is quit, 3Dsmax2 015 also.
I just want to quit the "Sub Form".

This is my code :

```
from PySide import QtGui,QtCore
import MaxPlus
import sys

class _GCProtector(object):
    widgets = []

app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
if not app:
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])

def main():     
    MaxPlus.FileManager.Reset(True)
    w = QtGui.QWidget()

    w.setFixedSize(300,360)
    w.setWindowTitle('Library')
    _GCProtector.widgets.append(w)
    w.show()

    main_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    main_layout.addWidget(First(),0,0,2,0)
    w.setLayout(main_layout)

def First():
    # FIRST FRAME
    FirstFrame = QtGui.QFrame()
    FirstFrame.setMaximumWidth(230)
    FirstFrame.setMaximumHeight(700)
    # LABEL RENDERER
    renderer_lb  = QtGui.QLabel("Renderer :")

    # COMBOBOX RENDERER
    renderer_cbx = QtGui.QComboBox()
    renderer_cbx.addItem("Vray")
    renderer_cbx.addItem("Octane")

    # LABEL FOLDER
    folders_lb = QtGui.QLabel("Folder :")

    # LIST VIEW FOLDER
    folders_lv = QtGui.QListView()

    # BUTTON ADD NEW OBJECTS
    addnewobject_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Add New Objects")

    # BUTTON NEW SET
    newset_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("New Set")

    # DEFINE THE FUNCTION FOR FIRST FRAME
    Firstbox = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    Firstbox.addWidget(renderer_lb,0,0)
    Firstbox.addWidget(renderer_cbx,0,1,1,3)
    Firstbox.addWidget(folders_lb,2,0,1,4)
    Firstbox.addWidget(folders_lv,3,0,1,4)
    Firstbox.addWidget(addnewobject_btn,4,0,1,2)
    Firstbox.addWidget(newset_btn,4,3)
    Firstbox.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
    FirstFrame.setLayout(Firstbox)

    #++++++++++++++++++++ COMMAND ++++++++++++++++++++
    addnewobject_btn.clicked.connect(addnewobject)
    newset_btn.clicked.connect(newset)
    return FirstFrame
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
def addnewobject():
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.setFixedSize(450,90)
    w.setWindowTitle('Select folder of new objects')
    _GCProtector.widgets.append(w)
    w.show()

    # LABEL FOLDER
    folder_lb = QtGui.QLabel("Folder : ")

    # TEXT EDIT OF LINK FOLDER
    linkfolder_txt = QtGui.QLineEdit()

    # BUTTON BROWSE
    browse_btn=QtGui.QPushButton("Browse...")

    # LABEL EXAMPLE
    ex_lb = QtGui.QLabel("( ex : SCH, faucet, K7 )")

    # BUTTON CANCEL
    cancel_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")

    # BUTTON OK
    ok_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("OK")

    # DEFINE THE FUNCTION FOR ADD NEW OBJECT WIDEGET
    browser = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    browser.addWidget(folder_lb,0,0)
    browser.addWidget(linkfolder_txt,0,1,1,4)
    browser.addWidget(browse_btn,0,5)
    browser.addWidget(ex_lb,1,0,1,5)
    browser.addWidget(cancel_btn,2,4)
    browser.addWidget(ok_btn,2,5)
    browser.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
    w.setLayout(browser)

    #++++++++++++++++++++ COMMAND ++++++++++++++++++++
    cancel_btn.clicked.connect(quitApp)
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------

def quitApp():
        quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And please give me the advise how to unavailable the "Main Form" when the "Sub Form" is opened, cause when "Sub Form" is opened, i still can push the "Add new objects" on the "Main Form" it open many "Sub Form".

Thanks so much .

Comment: why you have use `quitApp` as its event ?

Comment: I think that just is a name, i just a new guy, so that i dont understand , and i followed tutorial .

Answer (score 1):

You just need to connect the button to the widget's [close slot](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#close):

```
    def addnewobject():
        w = QtGui.QWidget()
        ...
        cancel_btn.clicked.connect(w.close)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, my code now it can run follow your comment.